# How to scrape a Modal Dialog in Internet Explorer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, webclient, html-agility-pack, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a PowerShell solution to scrape some pages in SharePoint (2013) Site Settings and I'm stuck on how to reference a ModalDialog that pops up during the scrape. Any suggestions how to do this?

I'm looking to pull the data from the input boxes and then click "Cancel" to return to the previous page.

The link that calls the modal is:

```
<td class='ms-authoringcontrols'>
   <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' class='ms-authoringcontrols'>
      <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_editBB1" onclick="OpenBestBet(&#39;https:\u002f\u002www.example.com\u002fsites\u002fusa\u002fproductqualitysupport\u002fPages\u002fdefault.aspx&#39;); return false;" href="#BestBet">Edit</a>
   </table>
</td>
```

The JS function that opens the modaldialog is:

```
function OpenBestBet(bestBetUrl)
{
    // make up the url to send to the BestBet page
    bestBetUrl = bestBetUrl?escapeProperly(bestBetUrl):bestBetUrl;
    var addedBestBets = document.forms[0].elements['ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_bestBet'].value ;
    var keyword = escapeProperly(document.forms[0].elements['ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_keyword'].value);
    var gotoUrl = 
        addQueryParametersToUrl('BestBet.aspx',['u','k','a'],[bestBetUrl,keyword,addedBestBets]);

    var dialogOptions = {width:500, height:450};
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', function() { SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen(gotoUrl,dialogOptions,AddBestBetCallback,[addedBestBets]); });
}
```

This is what it looks like on the page:
[image]

And the body tag of the modaldialog starts with:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="BestBet.aspx?u=https%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fsites%2fusa%2fproductsupport%2fPages%2fdefault.aspx&amp;k=PQSS&amp;IsDlg=1" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="BestBet">
    <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__REQUESTDIGEST" id="__REQUESTDIGEST" value="0xOBFUSCATED,29 Aug 2014 20:57:46 -0000" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/OBFUSCATED=" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
```

I'm using PowerShell 3.0, Net.WebClient, application.internetexplorer object, and also have HtmlAgilityPack but I'm not able to figure out how to reference the modaldialog. Any help would get great! Thanks

Comment: You might want to check into using Selenium
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: At first I was averse to using Selenium because of the learning curve and that it's outside PowerShell and MSIE, which I'm primarily using for this task. But I decided to try it out, thinking Selenium would expose a way to access the modal window from PS. Selenium is able to navigate to the page, open the modal, and close it, but it's not clear to me how to engage the modal window in PS. Any suggestions? I'm also trying to figure out how to get Selenium to do the full scrape and output to CSV for XML doc. I would also appreciate any pointers on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to open and close the Modal window in Selenium but didn't take the time to figure out how to scrape values from it using Selenium.

Using PowerShell I wasn't able to access any part of the Modal, but when checking the source code of the Modal window I noticed the full URL in the header and was able to construct the URL from information on the parent page. This allowed me to launch another IE instance in PS, open the URL not in Modal mode, scrape the content, and close the window.

The URL construction was a little tricky with Unicode encoding and URI Data encoding, but I got it worked out. I hope others find this helpful.